# hydronic heating register air locked

Tags: heating

Can I change the air relief valve on one of my hydronic heating registers without draining the system?

I have a water shutoff valve at the register and the system is cold. The boiler pressure shows 10 lbs.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a hot water system then what you are calling an "air relief valve" is actually a vent valve and "NO" the radiator has 2 connections and you would have to shut off both connections not just one.